# Unable to add custom Domain w/ Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I'm unable to map a custom domain to my Google App Engine app. The steps I've already taken are:

1. I'm the admin of the Google Apps account
2. I'm the owner of the Google App Engine Account
3. I've added the domain to the "Domains" section of Google Apps
4. I've verified ownership of the domain within Google Apps
5. I've correctly setup the MX records of the domain
6. I've checked that the domain was correctly setup using: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/

However, for the last 3 days in the Domains section of Google Apps it says "MX records setup validation in progress".

Additionally, when I go to add the domain within the Application settings of the Google App Engine account I get redirected to a sign in page (despite already being signed in, and an admin within Google Apps, and the owner of the Google App Engine app). Either way when I go to sign in again I just get redirected back to the signin page and I'm not able to get any farther.

Also, I have billing enabled for the App Engine account. I've configured app engine domains numerous times before and never had these issues. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Following @presveva's suggestion I setup a new Google Apps account (despite already having an existing one) and the first page after creating a new Google App was a server error. After refreshing the page and verifying ownership of the domain I went to add the domain to App Engine.

On the "Please accept the Google App Engine terms and conditions to continue" page, first of all no terms even showed (numerous XMLHttpRequest errors on the page), and after submitting "I accept. Continue to add this service" the next page stated "An error occurred while trying to install this application. Please try again later."

This process is horribly broke and would be great if Google addressed this.

Comment: have you tried doing this with incognito mode?

Comment: Just tried incognito mode and still get redirected back to the sign-in when trying to add the domain from app engine's application settings.

Comment: the domain you are try to associate with the GAE app is the `Primary Domain`?

Comment: @presveva no it is not the primary domain

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I too initially started with the domain as a non-primary domain on another account.  I wonder if anyone else is having this issue who didn't start that way.

Comment: I tried the same steps as before and Google must have fixed the "Please accept the Google App Engine terms and conditions to continue" page (but the terms still do not show and still getting some XMLHttpRequest errors). Either way I needed to create a new Google App account and couldn't use an existing one.

Comment: @adam Are you saying you were able to add your domain using the new Google Apps account?  I'm still not able to; I still get the *An error occurred while trying to install this application. Please try again later.* message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For now*, the only one way for using custom domain in GAE is signup a Google Apps account ([domains article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/domains)).
Notice that the domain need to be the primary domain of account, a new account for domain.

The docs I have linked mentions a free single-user account but it has been replaced by a 50$ credit for a business Google Apps account ([forum annunce](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM/discussion))

Comment: Note that Google Apps does NOT support adding GAE apps to non-primary domains. It's not clear - it presents itself with an error while accepting T&Cs just as @adam describes. https://support.google.com/a/answer/182081?hl=en

Answer (score 4):

I know this  this post is old but I ran into the same issue.

- All ready running Google Apps for my primary domain.
- Created a new app and registered a new domain name for that.
- Don't want to get a new payed Google Apps account for the app domain.

@presveva is right but there is one way around it.

- Use your current Google Apps account and add the app domain as a alias for your primary domain.
- Make the admin account of your Google Apps domain owner of the Google App Engine (GAE) application.
- Add the GAE app to your Google Apps account via the Google Apps admin interface.
- Setup a custom domain name for the domain alias, your new app domain.

Note: If you use Google Sites for your domain you can't use www. Disable sites if you want to use GAE.